# Can the OP comment highlighting be turned up a bit?

Tags: feature-request, design

This is a minor quibble but since the site's CSS is in review I thought I'd bring it up. I just found out, via [this MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79754/184688), that if you ask a question and then comment on the answers below it, your username gets a slight background shading. I was surprised to hear this since in three years of using the site I'd never seen anything like it but if you look closely it is indeed there.

Look, for example, at an example from [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197491/):

[image]

This shading is so slight it's essentially useless. Maybe trim the CSS to give it a bit more contrast? Otherwise just turn it off, there's not much point in having invisible features.

---

And while we're at this, I thought I'd open up the floor: are there other much-too-subtle changes in colouring which you think should get a fortifier on the CSS overhaul?

Comment: It's certainly more noticeable on Meta.Phys, but I've always thought it was visible.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, then. Or my monitor. But I imagine there's more people with eyes/screens like mine. And yeah, it's ever-so-slightly more visible on meta - but could still use a souping up.

Comment: To add more, you can see [http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197101/why-does-hamiltonian-follow-the-property-h-ij-h-ji] at the comment-section that at my first comment my name was distinctly shaded but at the later comments it got duller & duller!

Comment: @user36790 I don't see the comment highlighting changing in that comment thread. Both your first and your last signature link have `class="comment-user owner"`, which invokes the CSS `.owner { background: #F3F9FC none repeat scroll 0% 0%; }`.

Comment: I didn't even know this was a thing!